# Temporary function arguments that last during scope containing function call

Tags: c++

Consider a typical function that fills in a buffer:

```
const char* fillMyBuffer( const char* buf, int size );
```

Suppose this function fills the buffer with some useful data, that I want to use almost immediately after the call, and then I want to get rid of the buffer.

An efficient way of doing this is to allocate on the stack:

```
doStuff();

{
    char myBuf[BUF_LEN];
    const char* pBuf = fillMyBuffer( myBuf, BUF_LEN );

    processBuffer( pBuf );
}

doOtherStuff();
```

So this is great for my library because the buffer is allocated on the stack - being essentially no cost to allocate, use and discard. It lasts the entire scope of the containing braces.

But I have a library where I do this pattern all the time. I'd like to automate this a little. Ideally I'd like code that looks like this:

```
doStuff();

{
    // tricky - the returned buffer lasts the entire scope of the braces.
    const char* pBuf = fillMyBufferLocal();

    processBuffer( pBuf );
}

doOtherStuff();
```

But how to achieve this?

I did the following, which seems to work, but I know is counter to the standard:

```
class localBuf
{
public:
    operator char* () { return &mBuf[0]; }
    char mBuf[BUF_LEN];   
};

#define fillMyBufferLocal()   fillMyBuffer( localBuf(), BUF_LEN );
```

As a practical matter, the buffer is lasting on the stack during the entire lifetime of the containing braces. But the standard says that the object only has to last until the function returns. E.g. technically its just as unsafe as if I'd allocated the buffer on the stack inside the function.

Is there a safe way to achieve this?

Comment: `processBuffer` needs to take a length too

Comment: Beyond the scope of the question. Assume the returned buffer is a null terminated string, or is parsable by processBuffer somehow.

Comment: Define "seems to work". `<g>` That macro creates a temporary object of type `localBuf` and passes that object to `fullMyBuffer`. When the function returns, the temporary object gets destroyed. The pointer that `fillMyBuffer` returns is not valid. All of which is to say that this only works by accident.

Comment: According to the standard that is what is supposed to happen. thus my question, can I do this safely somehow?

Comment: Create the buffer in the caller, or change `fillMyBuffer` to allocate it on the free store.

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to keep the buffer on the stack? Of-course there's a little overhead for creating it on the heap, but are you doing this so many times per second that it becomes an issue?

Comment: @merlin: This is tight loops in MP code. Stack allocation will we thread local, and won't need to synchronize with global resources like the heap

Comment: @RafaelBaptista: Is a macro like the one in my updated answer viable?

Comment: I am physically scared of fixed length buffers.

Answer (score 3):

I would generally recommend your original solution. It separates the allocation of the buffer from filling it. However, if you want to implement this `fillMyBufferLocal` alternative, it will have to dynamically allocate the buffer and return a pointer to it. Of course, if you return a raw pointer to dynamically allocated memory, it's very unclear that the memory should later be destroyed. Instead, return a smart pointer that encapsulates the appropriate ownership:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> fillMyBufferLocal()
{
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[BUF_LEN]);
  // Fill it
  return buffer;
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
auto buffer = fillMyBufferLocal();
processBuffer(buffer.get());
```

Comment: Would work. But I'm looking for something that keeps the allocation in the stack.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you should want to do this. It just makes the code harder to understand.

Automatic storage duration means that when an object goes out of scope, it is destroyed. Here you want trick the system into something that *behaves* like creating an object with automatic storage duration (i.e. allocates on the stack), but without respecting the corresponding rules (i.e. without being destroyed when returning from `fillMyBuffer()`).

The closest, meaningful thing you can do in my opinion is to use a global buffer that `fillMyBuffer()` can reuse, or let that buffer be a `static` variable inside `fillMyBuffer()`. For instance:

```
template<int BUF_LEN = 255>
const char* fill_my_buffer()
{
    static char myBuf[BUF_LEN];
    // Fill...
    return myBuf;
}
```

However, I strongly suggest reconsidering your requirements, and either:

- Keep using the solution you are currently adopting (i.e. transparently allocate on the stack); or
- Allocate the buffer dynamically inside `fillMyBuffer()` and return a RAII wrapper (like a `unique_ptr`) to this dynamically allocated buffer.

**UPDATE:**

As a last, desperate attempt, you could define a macro that does the allocation and the invocation of `fill_my_buffer()` for you:

```
#define PREPARE_BUFFER(B, S) \
    char buffer[S]; \
    const char* B = fill_my_buffer(buffer, S);
```

You would then use it this way:

```
PREPARE_BUFFER(pBuf, 256);
processBuffer(pBuf);
```

Comment: can't be global. This is MP code. I know the desired behavior is atypical and so would be harder to understand. This would be used in the internals of a library that does this a lot. I'm comfortable with documenting the atypical usage for just this unit. Callers of the class won't have to deal with it.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista: So why not creating a macro that does the allocation of `myBuf` and then invokes `fillMyBuffer()`?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a class that contains a stack-based buffer and converts to char const *, e.g.

```
void processBuffer(char const * buffer);
char const * fillMyBuffer(char const * buffer, int size);
int const BUF_LEN = 123;

class Wrapper
{
public:
  Wrapper(char const * (*fill)(char const *, int))
  {
    fill(&m_buffer[0], m_buffer.size());
  }

  operator char const * () const { return &m_buffer[0]; }

private:
  std::array<char, BUF_LEN> m_buffer;
};


void foo()
{
  Wrapper wrapper(fillMyBuffer);

  processBuffer(wrapper);

}
```